# How Do I Use Factory Girl To Generate A Paperclip Attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, factory-bot

I have model Person that has many Images, where images has a Paperclip attachment field called data, an abbreviated version displayed below:

```
class Person
  has_many :images
  ...
end

class Image
  has_attached_file :data
  belongs_to :person
  ...
end
```

Person is required to have at least one Image attached to it.

When using FactoryGirl, I have code akin to the following:

```
Factory.define :image do |a|
  a.data { File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'support', 'file.png')) }
  a.association :person
end

Factory.define :person do |p|
  p.first_name 'Keyzer'
  p.last_name 'Soze'
  p.after_create do |person|
    person.assets = [Factory.build(:image, :person => person)]
  end
  # p.images {|images| [images.association(:image)]}
end
```

(N.B. I have also tried the code commented out above was also tried)
Most of the time when I run cucumber features, I get an error akin to the following:

> No such file or directory - /tmp/stream,9887,0.png (Errno::ENOENT)
>
> ...

Sometimes the tests run successfully.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is I am having here or how they use FactoryGirl and Paperclip together to achieve something like what I am trying to achieve?

I am using Rails 3.

Comment: Up vote on question just for using Keyzer Soze as you test name!

Comment: When I do this... photos get generated and placed in the public/system folder everytime I run the test suite. The photos don't get destroyed after the test suite is done running. Does anyone else notice this?

Answer (score 90):

You can use [fixture_file_upload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload)

`include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in your test helper, here is an example factory:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    avatar { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'photos', 'test.png'), 'image/png') }
  end
end
```

In the above example, `spec/photos/test.png` needs to exist in your application's root directory before running your tests.

Note, that `FactoryBot` is a new name for `FactoryGirl`.

Comment: This answer is totally right but it may be more clear to say that the TestProcess include needs to be included with the Factory and not simply in your spec_helper.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Andrew. You may also have to place "include ActionDispatch::TestProcess" before the FactoryGirl.define block (which isn't what happens in this gist: https://gist.github.com/313121).

Comment: Also, the `{ }` are required. It breaks without it

Comment: Further clarification: the `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` should be inserted at the very top of the factory file, **outside** the `FactoryGirl.define do...end` block.

Answer (score 50):

Newer FG syntax and no includes necessary

```
factory :user do
  avatar { File.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'rails.png')) }
end
```

or, better yet,

```
factory :user do
  avatar { File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/fixtures/image.jpg") } 
end
```

Comment: I like it, but bear in mind that rails 4 removes app/assets/images/rails.png, so you will need to account for that change :)

Answer (score 39):

Desmond Bowe over at Pivotal Labs [suggests avoiding fixture_file_upload](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/avoid-using-fixture-file-upload-with-factorygirl-and-paperclip) due to memory leak problems. Instead, you should set the paperclip fields directly in your factory:

```
factory :attachment do
  supporting_documentation_file_name { 'test.pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_content_type { 'application/pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_file_size { 1024 }
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Works for me. Also simple enough to not require an existing file in spec/test folder.

Comment: Besides avoiding memory leaks, this way the tests will be faster.

Comment: The mentioned blog post moved to [pivotal.io/blog](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/avoid-using-fixture-file-upload-with-factorygirl-and-paperclip)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with attachment validation on `content_type`. For that you need a valid file object.

Answer (score 25):

I've been using the code in the gist below:

Rails 2

http://gist.github.com/162881

Rails 3

https://gist.github.com/313121

Comment: Just wondering the same things and this works beautifully. Thanks. I put it in an initializer.

Comment: Something to note: The gist above uses the older FactoryGirl syntax. DanS answer uses the new syntax.

Answer (score 14):

```
file { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'filename.png')) }
```

Comment: This is the simplest functional solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try using ActionController::TestUploadedFile.  You can just set the file property to an instance of TestUploadedFile and paperclip should take care of the rest.  For example

```
valid_file = File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'support', 'file.png'))  
p.images { 
   [
     ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new(valid_file, Mime::Type.new('application/png'))
   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers in some cases can help, and the one actually helped in one of my situations, but when using a Carrierwave, the previous solution from this question didn't work out this time.

**FIRST APPROACH:**

For me adding an `after :create` solved the problem for me like this:

```
after :create do |b|
  b.update_column(:video_file, File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'sample.mp4'))
end
```

Setting inline video file like `video_file { File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/sample.mp4") }` didn't work out and it was reporting errors.

**SECOND APPROACH:**

Define a factory like this (change `personal_file` to your attachment name):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    personal_file { File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/personal_files/my_test_file.csv") }
    personal_file_content_type 'text/csv'

  end
end
```

And add these lines to the`config/environemnts/test.rb` :

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  url: "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/:attachment/:filename",
  use_timestamp: false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you testing exactly? That paperclip will successfully attach the file? That really seems like a test that paperclip should handle, not your application.

Have you tried

```
a.data { File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'support', 'file.png') }
```

We use Machinist instead of factory_girl and have just used things like

```
Image.blueprint do
  image { RAILS_ROOT + 'spec/fixtures/images/001.jpg' }
end
```

Though, we aren't really testing much when we do this, we typically just want to have a valid `Image` object.

Comment: I have models that require a valid association with a Paperclip-enabled model, itself with a valid attachment.