# Rails Rspec test with carrierwave image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I wrote an API which can return latest 5 Newsletter and its image, but I am stuck at writing its `rspec` test.

First of all, here is the relationship between model.

```
Newsletter has_many NewsletterImages
NewsletterImage belong_to Newsletter
```

Secondly, I thought that I need to create some data in test database, so I wrote following code in `rspec` file.

```
7.times do |i|
  n = Newsletter.create(title: "Test#{i}", content: "TestContents#{i}")
  2.times do |i|
    ni = NewsletterImage.create(newsletter_id: n.id, order: i)
    ni.image = File.open('xxx.png')
    ni.save
  end
end
```

So, I need to upload file in very test? Is there a better way to generate data and test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to make your test data. That way, you can write clean tests like

```
# /spec/factories/newsletter_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :newsletter do
    title "My newsletter"
    content "Some content"
  end
end

# /spec/factories/newsletter_image_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :newsletter_image do
    newsletter
    image fixture_file_upload( Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/example.jpg', "image/jpg")
  end
end

# spec/models/newsletter_spec.rb
image = create :newsletter_image
expect(image.newsletter.title).to eq 'My Newsletter'
```

With all of the details of how the models are created hidden in the factory definition files, it's then easy to share the code across many tests.

For more detail about adding carrierwave files to Factory Girl definitions, look for other answers such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952914/693349

Comment: Thanks, I have some direction.

Comment: BTW, it should be `title "My newsletter"` and  `content "Some content"`, remove the extra `:`.