# Using factory_girl with PaperClip 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, factory-bot

Does anyone know the proper way to create PaperClip 4.0 attachments with factory_girl, bypassing any of the PaperClip processing and validation?

I used to just be able to do the following in my factory:

```
factory :attachment do
  supporting_documentation_file_name { 'test.pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_content_type { 'application/pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_file_size { 1024 }
  # ...
end
```

This would basically trick PaperClip into thinking that there was a valid attachment.

After upgrading from 3.5.3 to 4.0, I now get a validation error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.attachment.attributes.supporting_documentation.spoofed_media_type
```

NOTE: The original discussion for PaperClip 3.X is here: [How Do I Use Factory Girl To Generate A Paperclip Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294824/how-do-i-use-factory-girl-to-generate-a-paperclip-attachment)

Comment: Opened issue in Paperclip repo: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1432

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to be caused by [line 61 in media_type_spoof_detector](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/263a498195d47563a6227be18cf4463c4c6e7903/lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb#L61).

Paperclip is trying to find the mime type of the "file" you have uploaded. When there isn't one, it's failing validation to protect you from file type spoofing.

I haven't tried this myself, but perhaps your best bet would be to use a real file, and set it using the `fixture_file_upload` method from `ActionDispatch::TestProcess`.

```
factory :attachment do
   supporting_documentation { fixture_file_upload 'test.pdf', 'application/pdf' }

   # This is to prevent Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files
   after_create do |attachment, proxy|
     proxy.supporting_documentation.close
   end
end
```

You will need to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in `test_helper.rb`

This was first posted [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload#952-To-use-in-testing).

Comment: Hm, does http://pivotallabs.com/avoid-using-fixture-file-upload-with-factorygirl-and-paperclip/ still apply?

Comment: I believe this is the reason for the `after_create` hook, that correctly closes the temp file? I might be wrong though...

Comment: Can you explain how the after_create hook works? I'm having trouble getting that to work. What is `proxy` supposed to be? When I run my test, `proxy` is nil.

Comment: `after_create` should run once FactoryGirl has created the model. The second parameter should be the object that FactoryGirl used to create the model. See the "has_many" section of http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations for more details.