# how to use paperclip with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, factory-bot

I am relatively new to rails. I want to include paperclip with FactoryGirl in my unit tests. A snippet from my code looks like

```
class User 

  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "200x200" 
    }

   validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type =>  /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

I am aware of this question [How Do I Use Factory Girl To Generate A Paperclip Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294824/how-do-i-use-factory-girl-to-generate-a-paperclip-attachment) but it is an old post.

I also want to note that, the images i want to test are not local, but a URL is provided to Paperclip to fetch the image and resize it. Is it possible to include paperclip inside the factories?.

Thanks a lot,
  Shady

Comment: Almost what is suggested in the old post i pointed to. Using "avatar" or paperclip keywords in my factory. I always get "undefined method" which is logically.

Comment: `avatar` is not a keyword. It just refers to paperclip attachment name which in your case is `photo`. You should try it with `photo` and not `avatar`.

Comment: Could you please share your `factory` details of `User model`.